# Maps API - city-block resolution?

Tags: geolocation, maps, latitude-longitude, openstreetmap

'City Block' definition:  The area (often a rectangle) bounded by 4 intersecting streets:
http://gyazo.com/46e1e6f0bbe97db8dd7dd19b0f38d016

Is there a convenient way of working out the nearest CITY BLOCK to a long,lat location?

If so, is there a way of getting the long,lat for, say, the lower left and upper right points of the 'City Block'?

I have a preference for a solution in Open Street Maps.

Answer (score 0):

The [OverpassAPI](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API) has an [around](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API#Around) query that allows you to get specific objects (for example ways tagged as [highway=residential](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag%3ahighway=residential)) around a given position. You still have to determine if and which of those streets define a city block and calculate their intersections (there should be a node at every intersection) in order to get lan,lon of those intersections.

You may also ask this question at the [OSM help](http://help.openstreetmap.org/) site.